# Advantages of block-based simulator versus equation-based simulator

Tags: simulation

I am mostly using Modelica, an equation-based simulator.

I assume that block-based simulators like Simulink have their strengths and are better at some tasks, but I am wondering what those are. It seems like everything a block based simulator can do, an equation-based simulator can do nearly as well or better. For example, Modelica supports discrete states, directional (causal) links and other block-based features.

I realize that Simulink has a lot of pre-existing models. For example, if you are interested in simulating beam forming, you can buy a beam forming module for Simulink.

However, assuming that I do not want to buy or leverage existing Simulink models, why would I want to bother with Simulink at all? What is the advantage that a block based simulator has?